# "For THE use in a virtual power plant" or "for use in a virtual power plant" and other "the" cases

Tags: grammar

So a friend of mine just proof read my masters thesis and pointed out some errors which I think sound weird. He is probably right, but since one is in my title (*facepalm) and I need to fill in some special request to change it I wanted to double check.
Is it: "Simulation of ... for THE use in a virtual power plant" or is the "the" wrongly placed there?

Also: I am using some components from an online library called "Windpowerlib". So I always referred to it as: These functions are implemented from THE windpowerlib. He told me the "the" is wrongly placed there as well.

Can someone confirm? (and maybe explain because it sounds superweird to me)

Comment: (a) 'For use in' is a set phrase (it's probably in dictionaries as a 'headword') and certainly shouldn't have a definite article. I could, given time, perhaps come up with a sentence where 'for the use in' makes sense, but it would take some contriving. // You're modelling on 'in the library' here, but 'Windpowerlib' is a name. Would you say "in the Powerpoint", "in the Word", "in the Excel", "in the Wikipedia"?

Comment: What I do is I take stuff FROM the library and use it in my program. For me the logical comparism would be that I get a book from THE library rather than from library.

Comment: You look up a word _in the dictionary_ not _in dictionary_, but _in Ozdic_ rather than _in the Ozdic_.  Someone might have worked _for the American Oil Company_, but _for AMOCO_ not _for the AMOCO_.  Built _by Alco_, not _by the Alco_. _Inside / to / with / by / for ... Skylab_ (see the Wikipedia article). It is normal to use no article with proper nouns, and this is normal practice even when notional pairing with the headnoun (library, dictionary, company, laboratory ...) of a compound would indicate otherwise. And 'Windpowerlib' is hardly genericised yet.

Comment: I think we should have the full title / sentence. Is it the simulation being used in the power plant, or a simulation to show the thing in the simulation should be used in the power plant?

Comment: From the Windpowerlib library. From Windpowerlib. I agree it's a little confusing because "lib" comes from "library", but it's still part of the name.

Comment: What sounds “weird” to me is a Masters candidate starting a question with “so”. Others may think it unfriendly of me to say this, but I think I’m doing you a favour saying so.

Comment: Abstract nouns do not require a determiner.**Use of firearms outside the firing range is prohibited". Same usage as yours.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend is correct.

In "for use" "use" is uncountable and does not require a determiner. In fact it would be incorrect to use one as "the" has the effect of implying "of which we are aware" to its noun.

As far as "Windpowerlib" is concerned,it is a name and all names are uncountable (there are a few exceptions, but those need not worry you.)

Comment: "rice" is uncountable but it still takes "the": "the rice". [Proper nouns](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/proper_noun) (generally) don't take any articles, e.g. "Greybeard", "CJ Dennis", etc. "Windpowerlib" being a name is a proper noun. [use (noun)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/use#Noun): **use** (_countable and uncountable_, _plural_ **uses**). Since "use" can be either, you should explain more why it is uncountable here, i.e. how does one tell whether it's countable or uncountable?

Comment: @CJDennis You said: ""rice" is uncountable but it still takes "the": "the rice""  I said "*In "for use*" "use" is uncountable and does not **require** a determiner." - to require X ≈ for X to be necessary. You are stating a generality, ("the" may qualify countable and uncountable nouns) with which I agree, but I am citing a specific example. "Use", in the example, is not qualified by a determiner, "for use" is correct, *ergo* "use" is uncountable.

Comment: I was comparing "rice" to "Windpowerlib", not "use". "use" was a second point. I still think you should explain how one distinguishes between countable and uncountable, rather than having to trust the judgement of others.

Comment: @CJ Dennis I think that "how one distinguishes between countable and uncountable" is a bit of a tall order given the contextual nature of these nouns and nouns in prepositional phrases where that noun is itself qualified. I have looked at various threads on uncountable nouns, and none are very satisfactory, and yet these have uncriticised answers The OP could do the same thing. I could say "in this case "use" is a generality and is therefore uncountable" but this would lead to the next question of why "in a ... power plant" does not make it specific? And that would be the wrong question.